# Schengen visa from UK French consulate

Tags: schengen, france, turkish-citizens, uk-residents

I am going to be in UK for six weeks for research purposes, doing my PhD currently. I have a friend's wedding in France I'd really like to go so need a visa for a couple of days.

How hard it is? I am a Turkish citizen, and will have a student visa from the University of Liverpool. I know it is a short-term visa, but for a wedding and in case of an invitation letter and so on, do you think they will push it too hard?

Comment: Given your premise and what you have told us  it should relatively straight-forward exercise for them to conclude that you do not qualify for a UK application.  You should apply in Turkey before you leave.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to apply for the Schengen visa from your usual place of residence, with all the usual documents.

The UK visa has two effects. It establishes your travel history, and it gives you a destination for onward travel. So it might help a little, but you should not get sloppy in your Schengen visa applications.